# Interpolating NA's by group using dplyr on multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, na, zoo

I have a data frame like this:

```
> head(df1)
  iso year var1 var2 var3
1 XXX 2005  165   29 2151
2 XXX 2006  160   21 2139
3 XXX 2007   NA   NA   NA
4 XXX 2008  184    9 3640
5 XXX 2009   NA   NA   NA
6 YYY 2005  206  461 8049
```

I want to replace the `NA`'s of intermittent years based on the years around it and the `NA`'s in years at the beginning and end of the range by carrying backward and forward the outer most non-NA observation.

My code to do this for one column is:

```
df1 %>% 
 group_by(iso) %>%
 mutate(var1 = na.approx(var1, na.rm = FALSE, rule = 1)) %>%
 mutate(var1 = na.locf(var1, na.rm = FALSE)) %>%
 mutate(var1 = na.locf(var1, na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = TRUE))
```

This works, so now I want to do this for all columns in one go (there are more than 3 and they are not numbered like in my example). This I pieced together from the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46847436/apply-a-function-to-several-columns-at-once-with-mutate) question. I omitted the two calls to `na.locf`.

```
columnnames <- c("var1, "var2", "var3")
df1 %>%
 group_by(iso) %>%
 mutate_at(.vars = vars(columnnames), .funs = funs(na.approx(., na.rm = FALSE, rule = 1)))
```

This throws me an error and a warning:

> Error in approx(x[!na], y[!na], xout, ...) :
> need at least two non-NA values to interpolate
> In addition: Warning message:
> In xy.coords(x, y, setLab = FALSE) : NAs introduced by coercion

I think I understand the error, but I did not get it when I used the first piece of code on `var1`. The warning I don't follow. How cal I apply my code to all columns in my data frame? I also tried putting evertything in a loop, looping over `columnnames` but that didn't work either (and it it probably not the best way to go about this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can re-write your code using `mutate_at` so that conversion can be done in  one go as:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)


df %>% 
  group_by(iso) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("var")), 
            funs(na.locf(na.locf(na.approx(., na.rm = FALSE, rule = 1),na.rm=FALSE),
                                                              fromLast=TRUE)))


# # A tibble: 6 x 5
# # Groups: iso [2]
# iso    year  var1   var2  var3
# <chr> <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 XXX    2005   165  29.0   2151
# 2 XXX    2006   160  21.0   2139
# 3 XXX    2007   172  15.0   2890
# 4 XXX    2008   184   9.00  3640
# 5 XXX    2009   184   9.00  3640
# 6 YYY    2005   206 461     8049
#
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text=
"iso year var1 var2 var3
1 XXX 2005  165   29 2151
2 XXX 2006  160   21 2139
3 XXX 2007   NA   NA   NA
4 XXX 2008  184    9 3640
5 XXX 2009   NA   NA   NA
6 YYY 2005  206  461 8049",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper No issue. Actually, that give me a chance to correct `mutate_at`:-)

Comment: I am sorry if I was not clear, but my actual column names are not `var1`, `var2` etc. so I cannot reference them like you suggested. Using @www 's var referencing and your nesting of functions made it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use `na.approx` with `method = "constant"` (same as `na.locf`) and `rule = 2` (means extend nearest value to leading and trailing NAs).  If you want the NAs to be linearly interpolated instead remove the `method="constant"` argument.

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(iso) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-iso), funs(na.approx(., method = "constant", rule = 2))) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  iso    year  var1  var2  var3
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 XXX    2005   165    29  2151
2 XXX    2006   160    21  2139
3 XXX    2007   160    21  2139
4 XXX    2008   184     9  3640
5 XXX    2009   184     9  3640
6 YYY    2005   206   461  8049
```

### Note

`df1` in reproducible form is:

```
df1 <- 
structure(list(iso = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("XXX", 
"YYY"), class = "factor"), year = c(2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2005L), var1 = c(165L, 160L, NA, 184L, NA, 206L), var2 = c(29L, 
21L, NA, 9L, NA, 461L), var3 = c(2151L, 2139L, NA, 3640L, NA, 
8049L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6"))
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly this interpolates the data for 2007 for `XXX` as the average of 2006 and 2008, but applies the 2008 data to 2009?

Comment: No. As explained in the answer  wth `method="constant"` it works like `na.locf`. It fills in the NAs with the most recent prior non-NA like `na.locf` does but also it fills in leading NAs with the first non-NA.  I have added the output to the answer.  Look at `?na.approx` and for the `method` and `rule` arguments look at `?approx`.

Comment: Okay, thanks. That is not what I was looking for here, but it is good to know.

Comment: The question uses `na.locf` suggesting that that functionality was what you wanted to use. but if you want linear interplation of surrounding points remove the `method = "constant"` argument as the default for `na.approx` is to employ linear interpolation.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `mutate_at`. The key is to specify the right columns in the `vars` argument, which uses the same rule as the `select` function. Therefore, in this case, `vars(starts_with("var"))` will also work.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(iso) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-iso, -year), funs(na.approx(., na.rm = FALSE, rule = 1))) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-iso, -year), funs(na.locf(., na.rm = FALSE))) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-iso, -year), funs(na.locf(., na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = TRUE)))
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
# # Groups:   iso [2]
#   iso    year  var1  var2  var3
#   <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 XXX    2005   165    29 2151 
# 2 XXX    2006   160    21 2139 
# 3 XXX    2007   172    15 2890.
# 4 XXX    2008   184     9 3640 
# 5 XXX    2009   184     9 3640 
# 6 YYY    2005   206   461 8049
```

**DATA**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "  iso year var1 var2 var3
1 XXX 2005  165   29 2151
2 XXX 2006  160   21 2139
3 XXX 2007   NA   NA   NA
4 XXX 2008  184    9 3640
5 XXX 2009   NA   NA   NA
6 YYY 2005  206  461 8049 ",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: why you have used three different `mutate_at`? Can you add some comments for better understanding?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base solution:

```
ave(df,df$iso, FUN =function(y){
  if(nrow(y) > 1) y[3:5] <- lapply(y[3:5], function(x) approx(y$year,x,y$year,rule=2)$y)
  y
})

#   iso year var1 var2   var3
# 1 XXX 2005  165   29 2151.0
# 2 XXX 2006  160   21 2139.0
# 3 XXX 2007  172   15 2889.5
# 4 XXX 2008  184    9 3640.0
# 5 XXX 2009  184    9 3640.0
# 6 YYY 2005  206  461 8049.0
```