# Replace values across multiple varibles in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have a dataframe with 82 variables. Many of the variables contain alphabetic letters, which I want to change into a set of numbers. I can do this column-by-column, number-by-number using the code below:

```
 library(tibble)
 mydf <- tribble(~Var1, ~Var2.a, ~Var3.a, ~Var4.a,
            "A", "b", "b", "d",
            "B", "w", NA, "w",
            "C", "g", "k", "b",
            "D", "k", NA, "j")

 newdf <- mydf %>%
   mutate(Var2.a = ifelse(Var2.a %in% c("m", "p", "w", "h", "n"), 1, Var2.a),           
          Var2.a = ifelse(Var2.a %in% c("k", "b", "g", "j", "f", "d"), 2, Var2.a),
          Var3.a = ifelse(Var3.a %in% c("m", "p", "w", "h", "n"), 1, Var3.a),           
          Var3.a = ifelse(Var3.a %in% c("k", "b", "g", "j", "f", "d"), 2, Var3.a),
          Var4.a = ifelse(Var4.a %in% c("m", "p", "w", "h", "n"), 1, Var4.a),           
          Var4.a = ifelse(Var4.a %in% c("k", "b", "g", "j", "f", "d"), 2, Var4.a))
```

But this will take a lot of time for the 70+ columns I need to change!

All the variables of interest have a matching letter combination in the variable name (".a" in the example data), so I should be able to use an `ifelse` statement on these columns using `contains()`. However I can't work out how to do this!

I have looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46847436/680068), which I think is getting me close, but I can't work out how to embed an if-statement into it:

```
 newdf <- mydf %>%
   mutate_at(vars[2:4] = ifelse(vars %in% c("m", "p", "w", "h", "n"), 1, vars)
```

But I get the error `Error in vars[2:4] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`. I think the brackets are wrong here, and probably also the use of `vars`!

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/46847436/680068

Comment: This is close to answering my question, but one thing I'm not sure how to do with this is put it within an `ifelse` statement. I'll amend my answer - thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this example:

```
# custom function, I prefer case_when (we could use nested if_else if needed.)
foo <- function(x){
  case_when(
    x %in%  c("m", "p", "w", "h", "n") ~ 1L,
    x %in%  c("k", "b", "g", "j", "f", "d") ~ 2L,
    TRUE ~ NA_integer_)
}

mydf %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Var2.a:Var4.a), foo)

# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#   Var1  Var2.a Var3.a Var4.a
#   <chr>  <int>  <int>  <int>
# 1 A          2      2      2
# 2 B          1     NA      1
# 3 C          2      2      2
# 4 D          2     NA      2
```